# how to minimize reflows when add circles to svg

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

In some particular situation, I want to draw 100000 circles with random center coordinate , radius and color to a area of page. Draw the whole things simultaneously may cause page freeze problem. So I want to draw them one by one. But as a series of tests, this can not really improve the performance, as every time a new circle element added cause the whole page reflows and repainting.

below is my code to do these things:

```
  function createCircle(cx,cy,r, color){
    let circle = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'circle')                              
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', cx);                                              
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', cy);                                              
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', r);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'style', `fill: none; stroke: ${color}; stroke-width: 1px;`);
    return circle
  }                                                                   
  let svg = document.getElementById('mysvg')
  function drawRandomCircle(){
    let x = 300*Math.random()
    let y = 100*Math.random()
    let maxR = Math.min(100-y,y,300-x,x)                                                
    let r = maxR * Math.random()
    let color = '#' + Math.floor(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16)                 
    let c = createCircle(x,y,r, color)                                                  
    svg.appendChild(c)
  }

  let count = 0
  function drawCircles(){
     if(count < 100000){
       drawRandomCircle()
       count ++
       requestAnimationFrames(drawCircles)
     }
  }
  drawCircles()
```

Comment: You can remove the element from the DOM, add all your circles, and then add the element again (or clone it, do you manipulation, and then replace the active element)

Comment: How do you know that this causes a reflow and repaint of the whole page? SVG is made in such a way that reflow of other content is not necessary, moving your circle will never have any incidence on the positioning of your HTML document, and most browsers if not all use canvases for the paintings, and will thus only repaint the svg's canvas.

Comment: @Kaiido I have monitored the whole process in chrome dev-tool. the more circles added, the more 'Composite Layers phase' costs.

Comment: @some Ok, I'll try it.

Comment: Ok, that paintings of this area cost more and more, that's quite normal, but [there is no reflow involved](https://jsfiddle.net/r0nLa9d1/1/). Now, I'm not quite clear as whether you really need the animation to appear or if this was just an attempt to solve the initial problem that 100,000 circles is just too hard to compute, not if you really need an svg image, or if a raster could also do.

Comment: Yes, a raster may do that job as well and more reasonable. But for some stupid reason I can only use svg in this project in my company. Is there any way I can do to make the svg painting circles incrementally instead of repainting the whole canvas every time.@Kaiido

Comment: Well [do the DOM manips when the svg is not in the Document, and append it only then](https://jsfiddle.net/of9pkmgj/). But even then, every new paint of the svg will kill your page. Can't you bend a bit these rules [so that you can use a <canvas> instead](https://jsfiddle.net/of9pkmgj/1/)?

Comment: Thanks for you patient and kindly help. I have one more question, multiple element located in same area will cause that area repainting. Is there any way, I can just cover one element above another in same area, but not trig a repainting.@Kaiido